# Jersey 1.18 in weblogic 12.2

Tags: web-services, jersey, weblogic12c

I have a web service in a weblogic **12.1** server (where it works) that I now have to transfer in a new weblogic **12.2** server. In my WEB-INF/lib jars I have jersey 1.18 files. However when I deploy it, it seems that Jersey 1.18 gets overridden by Jersey 2.21 and by calling the web service I get a "404 not found error". Application.wadl now has `<ns0:doc ns1:generatedBy="Jersey: 2.21.1 2015-09-16..."/>` so I guess that's where the problem is.

I tried putting a weblogic.xml file in WEB-INF with:

```
<container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

but nothing changed. How can I force using Jersey 1.18 ?

Answer (score 3):

weblogic 12.2.x does not support jersey 1.x server api any more. It is better to use jersey 2.x api. For the 404 issue, I think you can use this link to change your app .

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/RESTF/jersey-back-comp.htm#RESTF385

Answer (score 0):

You may resolve the issue by changing your web.xml:
Before:
`<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>`
After:
`<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>`

Answer (score -1):

A safer way to enforce the library version you need is to use shared-libs and reference then in the weblogic.xml file. Here's a sample so you can take a look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
           http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:library-ref>
       <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
       <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
       <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

I invite you to access this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF290) to get the detailed process on how to register your jersey lib as shared libs on weblogic instances.